# Success ratio of petition

Tags: india, government, petition

I self-drafted a Public Interest Litigation petition (Criminal) against the appointment of the Director (HR) of a Central Public Sector Enterprise in India against whom multiple complaints of corruption including complaints by several Members of Parliament are pending.

I collected information through file inspection and found that a CBI inquiry was also going on against him. Despite all this, the Appointment Committee of the Cabinet Secretariat appointed him as Director (HR) ignoring all the complaints as well as the CBI inquiry. I have been given to understand that the CBI inquiry is at Preliminary Inquiry stage i.e. FIR has not been registered yet so far.

What is the success ratio for such a petition? Many workmen are adversely affected by the atrocious, arbitrary, and highhanded attitude of this Director.

Comment: [There is some data](https://www.scobserver.in/journal/on-an-average-the-court-receives-over-25000-pils-a-year/) on the total number of PIL petitions in India but I'm not sure if the outcomes are tracked or not.